Navigation/Redirection from Widget's button is not working using UIKit
My entire application is in UIKit. I have created a medium-sized widget, which has three different buttons. I want to redirect to the respective screens when clicking on the widget buttons. I have handled the button click event using AppIntent. There are three buttons: "View Contacts," "Add Contact," and "Delete Contact." All three view controllers are created in UIKit. Now, I don't know how to navigate to the ViewContactsVC.swift file when tapping on the "View Contact" button from the widget. When I click on the View Contact button click event is working.
struct AppWidgetEntryView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var widgetFamily

    var body: some View {
        Group {
          if widgetFamily == .systemMedium {
              MediumWidgetView()
            }
        }

    }
 }
struct MediumWidgetView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Button(intent: ViewContactsAppIntent()) {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("View Contact")
                        .font(.system(size: 15.0))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .frame(height: 35.0)
                    
                    Image("contact_view")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 20)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)

            Button(intent: AddContactsAppIntent()) {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Add Contact")
                        .font(.system(size: 15.0))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .frame(height: 35.0)
                    
                    Image("add_contact")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 20)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)

            Button(intent: DeleteContactAppIntent()) {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Delete Contact")
                        .font(.system(size: 15.0))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .frame(height: 35.0)
                    
                    Image("delete_contact")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 20)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
        }

}

ViewContactsAppIntent.swift
    import Foundation
    import AppIntents

    struct ViewContactsAppIntent: AppIntent {
        static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "View Contacts Clicked"
   
        init(){}
        
        func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
            print("View Contact Clicked")
            //Navigate to ViewContactVC.Swift
            
            return .result()
        }
    }

